# how to change the setting of Stained Glass Texture?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, texture

I want to set Stained Glass Texture on the part of my painting ,but when I use this texture and Set the cell size , color of some parts are white , can I do something that these parts become transparent ? or what color I want?

I added  Image that shown my problem :
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot affect the bleeding white areas, but instead of struggling with them, make your shape larger then needed and hide the white areas by clipping mask.

Additionally, you can hide the upper border just by moving the Glass layer below the wavy one or using the waves as a mask.